# Bootsrap is not being applied on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm following a bootstrap tutorial. The bootstrap styles are not being applied in my browser. Also all the required files are in the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">

      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SHUBHI KHANDELWAL </a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">WORKS</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>  
  </div>

</nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a folder named css with the file bootstrap.min.css in it?

Comment: Check the console panel that any error showing, see any 404 found errors?

Comment: If all the files are in the same folder, then remove the 'css' part of `href="css/boostrap.min.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have error messages in the console?
Did you check the following html structure which need to be followed by bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/

Do you have all the files locally in the correct folder:
css/bootstrap.min.css
js/bootstrap.min.js

Please check the documentation here to correctly include Bootstraps:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Try Bootstrap CDN

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```